# LINQ to Entities Contains Query

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to use Contains() in a simple query but it is failing, with the error :

Unable to create a constant value of type 'NewsletterApp.Models.NewsletterUser'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Edit  The intellisense actually directs me to use the NewsletterUser  in Contains() -'(NewsletterUser item)'

I read that there were issues searching for an object using Contains() using EF with .NET 3.5, but I am using EF4.2 (also tried 4.1) with .NET 4.0 . 
Code is below:

```
        var db = new MyContext(); 

        var newsletterUser = db.NewsletterUsers.Find(UserID);
        var subscriberList = db.Subscribers
              .Where(x => x.NewsletterList.ListOwner.NewsletterUsers.Contains(newsletterUser))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you want this

```
var db = new MyContext(); 
var newsletterUser = db.NewsletterUsers.Find(UserID);
var subscriberList = db.Subscribers
          .Where(x => x.NewsletterList.ListOwner.NewsletterUsers
                     .Any(y => y.UserId == newsletterUser.UserId))
          .ToList();
```

Any() checks for the existence of a item that fulfils the criteria specified in the lambda: "y => y.UserId == newsletterUser.UserId".

The exception you were getting: "Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context" is due to limitations set by LINQ to Entities.  LINQ to Entities needs to resolve your query in a way that it can express to the database, and it can't do that with the Contains() method with anything other than a primitive type.

The thing is, the code you posted does run fine if you run it against an in memory collection (LINQ to Objects) - that's why it isn't flagged by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. Instead of comparing a property or field, you are comparing the whole object or entity, which can't be done in this manner.

Try the following code and it will work

```
var db = new MyContext(); 
var newsletterUser = db.NewsletterUsers.Find(UserID);
var subscriberList = db.Subscribers
          .Where(x => x.NewsletterList.ListOwner.NewsletterUsers.UserId.Contains(newsletterUser.UserID))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: NewsleterUsers is an IEnumerable so that code wont work. The intellisense actual directs me to use the object '(NewsletterUser item)'.

Comment: I don't know much about your context so can't exactly write the exact query....Can you elaborate as to what you want and show the entity class for NewsLetter and Subscribers....The main reason your query isn't working is because you are comparing objects instead of properties or fields....Think of it this way , can you compare class1 with class2 ....